# cannot resolve method "when"

Tags: mockito

I'm following the Vogella tutorial on Mockito and get stuck pretty much immediately. IntelliJ displays `cannot resolve method 'when'` for the class below.

...what did I miss?

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoTest  {

@Test
public void test1()  {
    MyClass test = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
    // define return value for method getUniqueId()
    test.when(test.getUniqueId()).thenReturn(43);

    // TODO use mock in test.... 
}

}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The method when() is not part of your class MyClass. It's part of the class Mockito:

```
Mockito.when(test.getUniqueId()).thenReturn(43);
```

or, with a static import:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

...

when(test.getUniqueId()).thenReturn(43);
```

Comment: Strange, IntelliJ normally figures this stuff out. Thx!

Comment: It does: you're telling the compiler "I want to call the method when() on the object test of type MyClass", and it tells you "sorry, but there is no method when() in MyClass".

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get when from the mocked class. You need to do something like:

```
...
MyClass test = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
Mockito.when(test.getUniqueId()).thenReturn(43);
...
```